# Meaning of Payload-LINQ

Tags: linq, streaminsight

I am new for LINQ, the above code is executing fine for me.

But I couldn't figure out why in the last sentence c.payload.Quantity is written instead of c.Quantity.

When I googled I came to know that the value Quantity is obtained from the payload that we get from the results in c, does that mean that the payload is the final output of filterQuery?

```
var orderData = new[]
{
 new {OrderDate = new DateTime(2011,1,1,8,30,00), ItemID = "100", UnitPrice = 0.99, Quantity =5},
 new {OrderDate = new DateTime(2011,1,1,8,31,00), ItemID = "200", UnitPrice = 3.99, Quantity =2},
 new {OrderDate = new DateTime(2011,1,1,9,02,00), ItemID = "200", UnitPrice = 1.50, Quantity =1},
 new {OrderDate = new DateTime(2011,1,1,9,07,00), ItemID = "100", UnitPrice = 4.10, Quantity =3}
};

var orders = orderData.ToPointStream(Application,ev=>PointEvent.CreateInsert(ev.OrderDate,ev),AdvanceTimeSettings.StrictlyIncreasingStartTime);

var filterQuery = from o in orders where o.Quantity>=2 select o;

(from o in filterQuery.ToIntervalEnumerable() where o.EventKind == EventKind.Insert 
select new {o.StartTime,o.EndTime,o.Payload.Quantity}).Dump("Heading");
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to know without knowing what ToPointStream and ToIntervalEnumerable does but it looks like one of them is creating Payload

Comment: ToPointStream converts cepstream to point event streams and ToIntervalEnumerable takes the filterQuery output and flips it into interval(This might not be so clear, coz I am beginner). Yeah, I guess filterQuery is creating a PayLoad, but I wanna make sure of it and know the exact meaning of PayLoad.

Answer (score 0):

ToIntervalEnumerable transitions from the StreamInsight APIs and event model to a plain old .NET sequence. in the latter, in addition to the payload, you can access the system fields StartTime, EndTime, and EventKind. To avoid naming conflicts, the payload needs to be encapsulated (imagine the payload, which is defined by the user, had a field 'StartTime'!). this is the meaning of the Payload field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the clarification of my previous comment I would like to add ToIntervalEnumerable - "Converts a CepStream of interval events to an event sink that implements the IEnumerable interface." i..e it takes interval events and converts it into a event sink(listener- like a computer/server that some times handles event) that are capable of implementing IEnumerable interface(That performs iterations on a collections).